# Inline style in index.php does not display background image pulled from database

Tags: php, sql, inline-styles

I have an index.php which I have successfully filled with content from the relevant tables in a mysql database. However there is one section (events) that has a background image that is defined in the css. However after changing the css to a php and making sure to give mention `<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); ?>`, `background-image:url:"<?php echo $eventsrow[0]['filepath'];?>"` was throwing the style of the entire document out of whack apart from not showing the image.

So i decided to put the image call in the index.php instead, as I had done for the other sections, by using inline style: `<div class="monthevent" style="background-image:url("<?php echo $eventsrow[0]['filepath'];?>");">`

However the image does not appear at all. Is there something wrong with this? Would appreciate any light. A **var_dump** on the above variable, gives the correct value: ie. the filepath, but the image is not displayed; also I tried adjusting the path relative to the css (just in case), but no image turned up. Would appreciate any thoughts on what the issue might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use like this:

```
<div class="monthevent" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $eventsrow[0]['filepath'];?>');">
```

Not the double quotes inside the url, use single quotes to differentiate the url!

If you use double quotes:

```
<div class="monthevent" style="background-image:url("your_url.com");">
</div>
```

If you use single quotes:

```
<div class="monthevent" style="background-image:url('your_url.com');">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that did it! But could you explain why exactly - i thought single quote makes the string literal - so in nested quotes what exactly is the behaviour to be understood?

Comment: differentiates the URL from the style attribute.. you can also use `style='background-image:url("your_url.com");'>` though!